# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the X. Please make sure that the argument HttpService at index [1] is available in the Module context

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have a problem while was working with nestjs HttpModule

The error:
`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ShopService (PrismaService, ?). Please make sure that the argument HttpService at index [1] is available in the QaModule context.`

My ShopModule:

```
@Module({
    imports: [HttpModule],
  controllers: [ShopController],
  providers: [ShopService, PrismaService],
})

export class ShopModule {}
```

My QaModule:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [QaController],
  providers: [QaService, PrismaService, ShopService],
})
export class QaModule {}
```

What are the solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `ShopModule` to

```js
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  controllers: [ShopController],
  providers: [ShopService, PrismaService], // Prisma Service should probably come from PrisamModule
  exports: [ShopService],
})

export class ShopModule {}
```

and your `QaModule` to

```js
@Module({
  imports: [ShopModule],
  controllers: [QaController],
  providers: [QaService, PrismaService], // Prisma Service should still probably come from `PrismaModule`
})
export class QaModule {}
```

Services should only be declared in one module and then exported from that module if they need to be used elsewhere. In the module that declares the consuming service, the original module should be added to the `imports` array. This will ensure you have only one instance of each non-transient provider and will not need to be recreated in each module it is used in

Comment: Yep, that's absolutely worked for me. Thanks a lot, you're a genius